# Table layout not displaying

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, tablelayout

I have a form as follows-

```
var mainForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            layout: 'tableForm',
            border: false,
            title: 'This is title',
            bodyStyle: 'padding:5px',
            layoutConfig: { columns: 1 },
            defaults: { border: false, layout: 'form' },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'radiogroup',
                    columns: 3,
                    fieldLabel: 'Please select an option',
                    items: [
                        { boxLabel: 'Yes',  inputValue: '1', checked: true },
                        { boxLabel: 'No', inputValue: '2' },
                        { boxLabel: 'Not Sure',  inputValue: '3' }   
                    ]
                },
                {
                    border: false,
                    layout: 'tableform',
                    autoHeight: true,
                    layoutConfig: { columns: 2 },
                    items: [
                         { text: 'Enter value:', xtype: 'label', labelSeparator: ' ' },
                         new Ext.form.NumberField({ fieldLabel: ' ', hideLabel: true, width: 30, allowNegative: false, allowDecimals: false, minValue: 0, maxLength: 10 })
                    ]
               }
            ]
        });
```

But in this form, only radioGroup is displaying and the second panel (table layout) is not displaying below radiogroup at all.

However, if I add only a sinlge control like

```
{
    text: 'Enter value:',
    xtype: 'label',
    labelSeparator: ' '
},
```

it displays below radiogroup.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can't find in the docs the layout "tableForm". Perhaps using "table" will solve your problem ?. At least use the same case for both of your panel : 'tableform' or 'tableForm'

Answer (score 0):

Second item is missing the xtype, as per docs:

*If an xtype is not explicitly specified, the defaultType for the Container is used, which by default is usually panel.*